# How to align SVG path and solid logo?

Tags: reactjs, svg, sass

I am new to web development. I was working on my portfolio website to learn web dev and I encountered a problem where I am trying to animate my svg path and then fill it will color. Basically I shall animate by setting opacity of my solid logo to 1. Before that I have to align my svg path with my solid logo. I have been understanding most part of the code except for this viewBox thing in svg. I am unable to figure out correct attribute values. I have changed few values here and there and was able to put svg path (outlineLogo) in somewhat correct position but I guess I did some mistake and the scale of solid logo and outline logo (svg path) are different. please let me know how I can do this. Here is the code:

**index.js**

```
<div className="logo-container">
        <img className="solid-logo" src={LogoV} alt="V" />
        <svg
          width="559pt"
          height="897pt"
          version="1.0"
          viewBox="0 0 1100 500"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <g
            className="svg-container"
            transform="translate(0 457) scale(.1 -.1)"
            fill="none"
          >
            <path
              ref={outlineLogoRef}
              d="M5210.8,1.1l-5210,10270h1590l3690-7130l2950,5800l-576.1-17.5l-83.9-2.5h-1710l350-900l-930-1650l-1480,3900
        h6700L5210.8,1.1z M10501.3,10270.9l0.4,0.7H3800.1l0.3-0.7l1480-3900l0.4-1l0.5,0.9l930,1650l0.1,0.2l-349.8,899.5h1709.3
        l659.2,20L5280.8,3142.2l-3689.6,7129.1l-0.1,0.3H0l0.4-0.7l5210-10270l0.4-0.9L10501.3,10270.9z M1590.5,10270.6l3689.9-7129.7
        l0.4-0.9l2950.4,5800.9l0.4,0.8l-660.8-20H5860.1l0.3-0.7l349.9-899.8l-929.4-1648.9l-1479.4,3898.3H10500L5210.8,2.2L1.6,10270.6
        H1590.5z"
            />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

**index.scss**

```
.logo-container{
    z-index: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 609px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto;
    margin: auto;

    svg{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        transform: rotateZ(30deg) !important;

    }
    .solid-logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: auto;
        right: auto;
        bottom: auto;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotateZ(30deg);
        z-index: 1;

    }
}

.svg-container {
    stroke: rgb(0, 255, 208);
}
```

Comment: You can use Framer motion for this, instead of doing it from scratch. Yeah but if you are doing it from learning purpose's then you have to work around a little

Comment: Thanks @MeetBhalodiya for the reply. I want to learn how to work with viewBox and svg attributes and so would like to know how can i align my solid logo with outline logo(svg path) . Framer motion seems to be something i'd do for animation.

Comment: The path has the width of 10498.4 and height of 10268.4 and it is placed 1.6 to the left and 2.2 from the top. In theory the viewBox should be `viewBox="1.6 2.2 10500 10270.6"` to reach the edges of the SVG.